# SharePoint 2013 on premise - using Azure AD Application Proxy

Tags: 2013, active-directory

The two big questions I have about using Azure AD Application Proxy is as follows:

1. Can the Active Directory in Azure be used for outside emails aka (@gmail, @yahoo, ect. ect.)
2. Will the people picker be populated with using Azure AD Application Proxy?   This is a show stopper.

Stay tuned because if this is not answered we are having a POC to try to accomplish this.  Yes we know we will have to pay for the per user with Azure AD Premium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure AD Application Proxy is part of the Azure AD Premium P1 license (see [Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/)).

To your questions: Unfortunately you didn't specify what you want to achieve.. Do do *want* externals to access OnPremises SharePoint or should it be *avoided*? i'll try to answer, but you might include more details to your question.

### Question 1:

- The simpliest way to publish OnPremises SharePoint via Azure AD Application Proxy is via [Kerberos Constrained Delegation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-application-proxy-sso-using-kcd). Those implementations will not make you able to invite people by their E-Mail address. SharePoint PeoplePicker only resolves people from your **local** ActiveDirectory. You can control access to the application in AAD-Proxy - this is done via Azure AD Accounts. So set up your [Azure AD Connect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect) properly.
- As mentioned by Trevor, you can configure SharePoint as SAML application instead of Kerberos for Single-Sign-On. This will enable you to invite Azure AD users. But be aware that enabling SAML will also bring you a bunch of [drawbacks](https://www.google.de/search?q=sharepoint%20fba%20drawbacks) you have to consider when building your solution (link is for FBA, applies also for SAML as all of them work as trusted identity providers).

### Question 2:

- PeoplePicker will act via Azure AD Application Proxy like it behaves OnPremises if you configure AAD-Proxy via Kerberos.
- If you want to grant access to external users via Kerberos, you must create a User in OnPremises ActiveDirectory and it is synced via AAD-Connect to your AzureAD.
- Advantage: You have a full-featured user without any drawbacks from a trusted identity provider.
- Disadvantages:
  (1) PeoplePicker will resolve all users from AD which might show the external users unwanted details. Can be limited via [PeoplePicker-Property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261988(office.12).aspx), but this is not very practicable.
  (2) External users can enter your office and login to any Computer with their DomainAccount. This can effectively be limited with the "[Log On To...](https://serverfault.com/questions/800484/why-userworkstations-attribute-for-user-accounts-filled-with-domain-controllers)" setting in AD (fills userWorkstations AD-attribute).

Comment: MHeld in this solution the internal aka corporate folks are all required to login via using a VPN so that is covered with on-premise AD.  This is for outside individuals doing work with our company that we need to grant access for them in a separate CLOUD AD, but the people picker has to be used because we have to keep them separate from our infrastructure AD.

Comment: You could implement a SAML-Solution and improve it with http://ldapcp.com/. This will make PeoplePicker work, but all other SAML-Drawbacks still apply. If you do not want these drawbacks, you need an AD-Account and SharePoint PeoplePicker needs to reach this AD. Best solution here: Create a separate "External"-AD. Create a Two-Way-Trust between "Internal" and "External" AD. Limit the Externals access to SharePoint by configuring a Selective Trust with Allowed to Authenticate (https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2199426&seqNum=3).

Comment: We already have a solution that utilizes okta another third party that does this and a custom application that handles all the 3rd party contractor requests.    This is the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

The Azure AD App Proxy is simply a vehicle to let you access a resource behind a corporate firewall -- it is a "reverse proxy as a service" so to speak. It has no impact on the People Picker nor the ability to invite people from external resources.

You may be thinking of [Using Azure AD for SharePoint Server Authentication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/using-azure-ad-for-sharepoint-server-authentication). In this case, it is similar to any other SAML provider -- the People Picker will allow you to input any value as there is nothing to "resolve" against.